# Direct3D Texture Post-Processing/Copying

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, direct3d9

So I'm trying to implement some Direct3D post-processing, and I'm having issues rendering to textures.  Basically, my program looks like this:

```
// Render scene to "scene_texture" (an HDR texture)...

...

device->SetRenderTarget(0, brightpass_surface);
device->SetTexture(0, scene_texture);
// Render "scene_texture" to "brightpass_texture" using full-screen quad.
// This involves passing the quad geometry through a brightpass shader.

...

device->SetRenderTarget(0, ldr_surface);
device->SetTexture(0, brightpass_texture);
// Render "brightpass_texture" to "ldr_surface" using full-screen quad...
```

I've left out some parts b/c there is a fair amount of code (I'm just trying to get across the general idea).  Unfortunately, the above results in a blank screen.  Here is what I want to happen:

1. Render scene to a texture (HDR)
2. Render that texture to a second texture THROUGH a brightpass shader
3. Render the second texture to the visible LDR surface

Note that if I change the last line above from

```
device->SetTexture(0, brightpass_texture);
```

to

```
device->SetTexture(0, scene_texture);
```

Then everything works.  Note that I've tried skipping the brightpass shader and simply passing the pixels through, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was multisampling.  In the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMS` structure, I had enabled multisampling.  You can't render from one floating point texture into another floating point texture using the "full-screen quad" technique while multisampling is enabled.

Instead, I enabled multisampling in the HDR scene render target (`scene_texture`) and disabled it in the `PRESENT_PARAMS` structure.  This is good because I only needed multisampling for the scene rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you created the brightpass_texture with a render-to-texture flag?

Answer (score 0):

Does the debug runtime spew any errors out?  How do you get ldr_surface?

What happens if you render your scene straight to ldr_surface and bypass all the HDR stuff?  Thing will probably look a bit saturated but it should give you an idea ...

Comment: It works if I render straight to the LDR surface (with saturation, as you suggested).

Comment: hmmm ... what does the debug spew say?